# Where do I get a NEWLY manufatured computer terminal device?

Tags: displays, portable

I have a lot of old motherboards that I want to use for different projects and I've run into a major problem too many times now: every board has at least 1 serial port but rarely even the old VGA port. So I can't even operate those boards with my really "old" PC screens with stone-old VGA.

Are there new types of terminals nowadays that fullfil the purpose of a classic terminal but in an up-to-date way?

I've searched for something like that and **I didn't find anything**.

How I imagine a "modern" and "up-to-date" style terminal:

- uses the good old Serial Port
- 1 or 2 USB slots
- uses any battery, rechargable or not
- it is very small, preferably as small as a Samsung Galaxy Mini e.g.
- due to its size, modern/easy technology and simple purpose it should be accordingly very cheap, maybe up to 30 bucks MAX.

P.S.: Even if I would get an old terminal for free, it is still way too big and just wastes space, considering its single and nowadays extremely simple purpose.
And I would never pay for a Vintage one since from that perspective they have 0 value to me.

Comment: "I didn't find anything."  There's your answer.  Sounds very niche for something like what you want.